# Updating AngularJS scope after validating search form in Symfony2

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json, symfony

Hi fellow developers,

We have to rewrite a software application in Symfony2 with AngularJS, we use Symfony2 for the MVC purpose and AngularJS for the useful functions.

Here's our problem, we first display our clients in a table with the following code with AngularJS in my Symfony2 view :

```
var app = angular.module('appName', []);
app.controller('clientsCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
    $scope.loading = true;
    $http.post('{{ url(generatedScope) }}').then(function(response){
        $scope.clients = response.data;
        $scope.order = function(predicate){
            $scope.reverse = ($scope.predicate === predicate) ? !$scope.reverse :false;
            $scope.predicate = predicate;
        }
    },function(response){
        // TODO: handle the error somehow
    })
});
```

The `{{ url(generatedScope) }}` is a Twig var sent by the Symfony2 controller with the following :

```
 /**
 * @Route("/clients", name="index")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{       
    $form = $this->createForm(SearchClients::class, null);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isValid()){
        //TODO: Get form params and update angularJS scope somehow
    }

    return $this->render('clients/list.html.twig', [
        'generatedScope' => 'getClients',
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

`getClients` is the name of our default route when opening our view `clients/list.html.twig` (we're not using Doctrine) :

```
 /**
 * @Route("/clients/list/json", name="getClients")
 */
public function getClientsAction()
{
    $clients = new Clients($this->get('database_connection'));
    $response = new JsonResponse($clients->getClients());
    return $response;
}
```

so basically the `generatedScope` sent by our controller is : `127.0.0.0:8000/clients/list/json`, which is a json collection of our clients, We are then displaying clients in the table in our view this way :

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in clients | filter : test | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
    <td>#{{ x.cli_id }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.cli_lastname }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.cli_firstname }}</td>
</tr>
```

We have a search form, same page as the table displaying our clients, we collect first name and last name and call an action to retrive a json response in order to update our angular scope, we managed to retrive the response this way :

```
 /**
 * @Route("/tiers/list/json/search", name="searchClients")
 */
public function searchClientsAction(){
    $request = new Request($_POST);
    $request = $request->query->get('search_clients'); //form name
    $clients = new clients($this->get('database_connection'));
    $response = new JsonResponse($clients->searchClients($request));
    return $response;
}
```

We tried to send the view this route after validating the form in our `indexAction` :

```
if($form->isValid()){
    //TODO: Get form params and update angularJS scope somehow
    return $this->render('clients/list.html.twig', [
        'generatedScope' => 'searchClients',
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

But as you can see, it doesn't work.

So, how can we update an angularJS scope after validating a Symfony2 form ?

If anyone has encountered this issue... would be glad to read his opinion!

Best regards,

Dylan

Comment: in `searchClientsAction` why are you creating a new instance of `Request`? Just type hint the action with `Request $request` and that'll be populated by symfony. Unless Im misunderstanding your code could this be the problem?

Comment: From your wording i am not really sure you are submitting your form. If you are posting your form synchronously, then '{{ url(generatedScope) }}' should container "searchClients" route, but you are not passing data attribute specifically 'search_clients" where 'searchClientsAction' needs to query. On the other hand if you post a asynchronously, even if the post request contains all the necessary form posting data, it should return Twig generated html (from index page but with different generatedScope variable )

Comment: If you can get to if($form->isValid()) clause you could copy whole 'searchClientsAction' functions content(which i would not recommend). After we added angularjs to symfony backend we stopped using forms and started using backend as rest api. Then after you press search button  you would call $http with 'search_clients' to 'searchClientsAction' route, and assign $scope.clients = response.data;

Comment: @Kodvin was right, check out my own answer on the topic. Can tell me what you think about my solution, would be awesome ! Thanks guys :-)

Answer (score 0):

@Kodvin was right, i've come up with the following solution :

First of all, my S2 Controller :

```
 /**
 * @Route("/tiers", name="index")
 */
public function indexAction()
{       
    return $this->render('tiers/list.html.twig', [
        'generatedScope' => 'searchTiers',
    ]);
}
```

The generatedScope `searchTiers` define another function in my controller that fetch the datas :

```
/**
 * @Route("/tiers/list/json/search", name="searchTiers")
 */
public function searchTiersAction(Request $request){
    // TODO: A bit of refactoring needed there :-)
    $prenom = array('first_name' => $request->request->get('first_name'));
    $nom = array('last_name' => $request->request->get('last_name'));

    $params['first_name'] = $prenom['first_name'];
    $params['last_name'] = $nom['last_name'];

    $tiers = new Tiers($this->get('database_connection'));
    $response = new JsonResponse($tiers->searchTiers($params));

    return $response;
}
```

My form (Got rid of Symfony 2 forms... but I assume I can do that with S2 form aswell) :

```
<form method="post" ng-submit="submit()" id="search_tiers">
    <input ng-model="last_name" type="text" placeholder="Nom" name="last_name">
    <input ng-model="first_name" type="text" placeholder="Prénom" name="first_name">
    <input ng-model="submit" type="submit" value="Rechercher" name="submit_form">
</form>
```

Binding my inputs to the scope with `ng-model`

Calling the `submit()` scope function when clicking the submit button in my

```
app.controller('tiersCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
    $scope.submit = function() {
        var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: '{{ url(generatedScope)}}',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            data: { last_name: $scope.last_name, first_name: $scope.first_name }
        }

        $scope.loading = true;
        $http(req).then(function(response){
            $scope.tiers = response.data;
        },function(response){
            // TODO: handle the error somehow
        });
    }
});
```

`{{ url(generatedScope }}` is a Twig var calling my searchTiersAction() in my S2 controller to return data.

Finally, display data :

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in tiers">
    <td>#{{ x.tie_id }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.tie_nom }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.tie_prenom }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.tie_adresse }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.tie_cp }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.com_nom }}</td>
    <td class="visible-none">{{ x.tpt_nom }}</td>
</tr>
```

All I was missing was that I was losing my POST params when I was submitting my form, the Ajax request was totally lost... which is basically Angular's logic.

If you guys have any other solution, please tell us!

For the moment I hope it helps! :)

Dylan